# C# - How to get classname of editor part of default editor tool?

Tags: c#, winapi, editor, sendmessage, classname

I want to pass a string into default editor tool (notepad, notepad++, WordPad, ...) of a .txt file. But it requires that does not save it to file.
So I do below things

1. Start default tool -> success
2. Find child handle

   `IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(proc.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Scintilla", null); // Notepad++`

   `IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(proc.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null); // Notepad`
3. Send string to this handle

   `SendMessageA(child, 0x000c, 0, lParam);`

I have an issue at step#2. Because default tool is set by user, **how I can get the class name "Scintilla" or "Edit" or others?**
Another, I found these string by spy++

- Notepad++

[image]

- Notepad

[image]

Comment: I do not understand your question, you know how to retrieve the 2 HWND's ( based on the info provided ) but you have problem with what exactly?

Comment: I would try [EnumChildWindows()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494(v=vs.85).aspx) and then [GetClassName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582(v=vs.85).aspx). Another possible option might be to use the clipboard.

Comment: @m.rogalski I know which tool is default, but I can not get "Scintilla" or "Edit" classname because it maybe is wordpad, a web browser :( .... Is it always 2 HWND's?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I can get child handles and its classname, but how can I know this child handle is "Scintilla" or "Edit" or another child handle of parent handle.

Comment: If you do not know the HWND class names of other tools then it might be almost impossible to achieve. I would suggest you to just check all of the remaining tools ( eg. WordPad, gVim ... whatever ) and then based on the executable file name retrieve the child HWND to which you'll eventually send the message.

Comment: Why don't you use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx)? After all, that's what it's for: Automating a UI. The *ControlType* should be `UIA_DocumentControlTypeId`, irrespective of the editor you use. If you need to wait for the respective window to be created, use [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx).